# Logging into a forum using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to log into a forum using python requests. This is the forum I'm trying to log into: http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import sys

URL = "http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login"

def main():
    session = requests.Session()

    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {
        'ips_username': 'username',
        'ips_password': 'password',
        'signin_options': 'submit',
        'redirect':'index.php?'
    }

    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

    # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
    q = session.get('http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/index.php?app=members&module=messaging&section=view&do=showConversation&topicID=4314&st=20#msg26627')
    print(session.cookies)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(q.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The URL is the login page on the forums. With the 'q' variable, the session tries to access a certain webpage on the forums (private messenger) that can only be accessed if you're logged in. However, the status code for that request returns '403', which means that I was unable to log in successfully.

Why am I unable to log in? In the 'login_data', 'ips_username' and 'ips_password' are the HTML forms. However, I believe I have the actual log-in commands ('signin_options','redirect') wrong.

Can somebody guide me to the correct log-in commands please?

Comment: What is the response of `r`?

Comment: If you check the post parameters using `tamper data` you will find that you need  `auth_key`.

Comment: The response of r is 200, even if I type in the wrong log-in information.

Comment: @Chaker, could you clarify what you mean a bit more for me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a hidden input in the form `auth_key`

```
<input type='hidden' name='auth_key' value='880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024' />
```

So you need to parse it and pass it to the login page.
You could simply use **regex**

```
def main():
      session = requests.Session()

      # Get the source page that contain the auth_key
      r = requests.get("http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login")
      # Parse it
      auth_key = re.findall("auth_key' value='(.*?)'",r.text)[0]


      # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
      login_data = {
           'ips_username': 'username',
           'ips_password': 'password',
           'auth_key' : auth_key                                                                                                                      

      }
```

And the  rest should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by @Chaker in the comments, the login form requires you to send an `auth_key` that you need to read from an initial visit to a page first.

The `auth_key` is a hidden form field with a random value (generated and stored by the server), so every regular web browser sends that with the `POST` request. The server then validates the request and requires it to contain an `auth_key` that it knows is valid (by checking against its list of issued auth_keys). So the process needs to be as follows:

- Visit the front page (or any page below that probably)
- Read the value of the `auth_key` hidden field
- Create a `POST` request that includes your credentials *and* that `auth_key`

So this seems to work:

```
import re
import requests

USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

AUTH_KEY = re.compile(r"<input type='hidden' name='auth_key' value='(.*?)' \/>")

BASE_URL = 'http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + '/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process'
SETTINGS_URL = BASE_URL + 'index.php?app=core&module=usercp'

payload = {
    'ips_username': USERNAME,
    'ips_password': PASSWORD,
    'rememberMe': '1',
    'referer': 'http://fans.heat.nba.com/community/',
}

with requests.session() as session:
    response = session.get(BASE_URL)
    auth_key = AUTH_KEY.search(response.text).group(1)
    payload['auth_key'] = auth_key
    print("auth_key: %s" % auth_key)

    response = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    print("Login Response: %s" % response)

    response = session.get(SETTINGS_URL)
    print("Settings Page Response: %s" % response)

assert "General Account Settings" in response.text
```

Output:

```
auth_key: 777777774ea49e853634fbdc77777777
Login Response: <Response [200]>
Settings Page Response: <Response [200]>
```

`AUTH_KEY` is a regular expression that matches any pattern that looks like `<input type='hidden' name='auth_key' value='?????' \/>` where `?????` is a group of zero or more characters (non-greedy, which means it looks for the shortest match). The documentation on the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) should get you started with regular expressions. You can also test that regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/dC9rF6/1), have it explained and toy around with it.

**Note**: If you were to actually parse (X)HTML, you should always [use an (X)HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1599111). However, for this quick and dirty way to extract the hidden form field, a non-greedy regex does the job just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand a lot better now. However, when I use this code, it gives me an error on line 22: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//Desktop/Python34/Python_exercises/requests/#5.py", line 22, in <module>
    auth_key = AUTH_KEY.search(response.content).group(1)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'

Comment: @Carnageta I think you should replace `response.content` with `response.text`. For more information check [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).

Comment: @ChakerBenhamed indeed, that's exactly it. After all we're dealing with (possibly encoded) text and not bytes, so that's the right thing to do even with Python 2.x.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! Quesiton, how do I check whether or not I logged in successfully? Because even if I type in the wrong username/password, it still returns 200.

Comment: @Carnageta You could check for a `success key` for example `logout` or `welcome back`. Or you can check for the absence of `failure key` in your case it will be `Username or password incorrect.`

Comment: @Chaker, thanks for the info. How would I actually check for the absence of failure key? Sorry, I am kind of new to Python over the internet.

Comment: @Carnageta turn's out I had a bug in my earlier code (wrote `ips_username` twice, also for the password field). Now I've added a check `assert "General Account Settings" in response.text` - that message only appears in the response to a request to the settings page if authentication was successful.

Comment: @Carnageta and the success / failure keys that Chaker is speaking of is not something standardized in any way - it's basically just a marker that you pick yourself, depending on how the web application is implemented, that can be used to indicate success or failure. In my example I visit the settings page and check for the presence of the text `General Account Settings` in the response - but it really could be anything.

Comment: @Lukas Graf, thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept @Chaker's answer BTW, it should work just as well, and he was the first one to point out the `auth_key` ;-)

Comment: Question, I'm not really understand the "AUTH_KEY = re.compile' part. Is there a place I can go to get a better understanding of re?

Comment: @Carnageta the documentation on the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) should get you started. You can also test that regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/dC9rF6/1), have it explained and toy around with it.

Comment: Hi, another question. The line, 'auth_key = AUTH_KEY.search(response.text).group(1)', what does this piece do, and what does group(1) mean? Thank you!